# How to get first 50 post url from instagram

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I want to get the first 50 post for any public instagram url. To get the first 12 posts which are visible by default is easy and below code is doing that just fine but I am not sure how to access other urls which is visible when you hit "load more" button at the bottom and scroll further down for more. Is this possible? Can anyone help me with this?

```
Sub getData()

Dim urL As String, instaID As String, totalPost As Long, fRow As Long
Dim ie, var1, var2, a

urL = "https://www.instagram.com/nike/"
OUT.Range("A2:A" & OUT.Rows.Count).Clear

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True

fRow = 2

'----------------------
With OUT

    ie.navigate urL

    'Busy
    Do While ie.Busy
      Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set var1 = ie.document.getElementsByclassname("_mck9w _gvoze _f2mse")
    Do While IsObject(var1) = False
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        Set var1 = ie.document.getElementsByclassname("_mck9w _gvoze _f2mse")
    Loop

    Set var2 = var1(0).document.getElementsBytagname("a")

    For Each a In var2
        If Trim(a.href) <> "" And a.parentelement.classname = "_mck9w _gvoze _f2mse" Then

            .Range("A" & fRow) = a.href
            Debug.Print a.innertext & " " & a.parentelement.classname

             fRow = fRow + 1
        End If
    Next a


End With

'------------------
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub getData()

    Dim urL As String, instaID As String, totalPost As Long, fRow As Long
    Dim ie As Object, var1 As Object, a As Variant

    urL = "https://www.instagram.com/nike/"

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate urL

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do
        Set var1 = ie.Document.getElementsByclassname("_1cr2e _epyes")  ' wait for "load more"
    Loop While var1 Is Nothing

    var1(0).Click                                                       ' click "load more"

    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readystate <> 4                              ' not sure if this is needed
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For a = 1 To 4
        ie.Document.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 60000                      ' roll to bottom
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")                    ' wait for "fill in"
    Next a

    Set var1 = ie.Document.getElementsBytagname("a")

    Range("A2:A" & Rows.count).Clear
    fRow = 2

    For Each a In var1
        If Trim(a.href) <> "" And a.parentelement.classname = "_mck9w _gvoze _f2mse" Then
            Range("A" & fRow) = a.href
            Debug.Print a.innertext & " " & a.parentelement.classname
            fRow = fRow + 1
        End If
    Next a

    ' ------------------
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing. Just what I needed :)

Comment: change the "fill in" loop to something like 80 to get all the pictures